# Wraping link reference as AjaxCall with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to get href value, in such situation? 
I'm using jQuery and pure JS on my page;

```
<a href="somelink" onclick="asAjaxCall(this)">ololoText</a>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function asAjaxCall(elem) {
            var link = elem.getThatLinkSomehow(); //how to get "href"??
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: link,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#controlsContainer").empty();
                    $("#controlsContainer").append(response);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jquery you can use `.attr()` like so:

```
$(elem).attr("href");
```

or in plain javascript you can use `.getAttribute()`:

```
elem.getAttribute('href')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcqe2z7r/)

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in `elem.href`.

But you should not use `<a>` in this case - after your callback is done or if user tries middle-button click new page with useless address will be opened. Use simple `<div>` instead. Or at least stop event propagation.